# React - Optimizations with useRef (performance)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The difference between doing this

```
const Card = ({ contentType }) => {
   const isPost = useRef(contentType === "post");

   ...
}
```

and this

```
const Card = ({ contentType }) => {
   const isPost = contentType === "post";

   ...
}
```

is that in the first case, isPost will only be calculated one time, and memoized, and in the other case it will be calculated in every re-render, right?

So, if we had calculations like this one, where the value will be the same on every re-render, should we put them in a useRef?

I know that useRef is used to avoid value changes on re-renders, some kind of useState that doesn't re-render the component, but what about if that value is constant and calculated in the body of the component?

Note: I know that this seems something like a "personal opinion", but my question is about performance impact and the correct use of useRef hook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is that in the first case, isPost will only be calculated one time, and memoized, and in the other case it will be calculated in every re-render, right?

No. In both cases `contentType === "post"` is evaluated. Actually, you would get a different behaviour. With ref, if `contentType` change at any point, `isPost` will remain the same. Unless you update it with `isPost.current = contentType === "post"` somewhere else.

If you want to memoize, you'd do:

```
const isPost = React.useMemo(() => contentType === "post", [contentType]);
```

Is the above, in this scenario, really necessary? I'd say no. `React.useMemo` would need to compare the deps already, and `contentType === "post"` is already a very lightweight operation. In most cases you can just derive the state from state and props without worry too much.

Comment: "No. In both cases contentType === "post" is evaluated." --- But, if with useRef, when contentType changes, the value will still be the same, why is it evaluated again on a re-render?

Comment: The value you pass to useRef is the _initial value_. You could technically write your example as `const refValue = contentType === "post"; const isPost = useRef(refValue);`, it's the same thing - the refValue expression will run every re-render anyway, and isPost.current !== refValue if  `refValue` change after initialisation - `isPost` becomes something you need to update separately, which you don't really have to. Just go with `const isPost = contentType === "post";`

Comment: If you really want to use useRef for some reason,
`const isPostRef = useRef();`
`if(isPostRef.current === undefined) isPostRef.current = contentType === "post"`

Answer (score 1):

> is that in the first case, isPost will only be calculated one time,
> and memoized, and in the other case it will be calculated in every
> re-render, right?

Yes, every time.

> So, if we had calculations like this one, where the value will be the
> same on every re-render, should we put them in a useRef?

Almost always no.

1. For performance optimizations better to use `useMemo` and `useCallback`, e.g. `const isPost = useMemo(() => contentType === "post", [contentType]);`
2. All performance optimizations have their own "cost" - either some overhead like useMemo or more complexity and pitfalls like useRef (can change value inside ref without rerender, in some cases it's useful).

So no point to optimize something so simple, when need to normalize 300kb of data for D3 chart and don't recalculate it every rerender can use useMemo.

useCallback useful because can have function with same signature and avoid unnecessary rerenders in child components.